# gather múltiplo com 4 colunas resultantes "juntas"

Tags: r, data.frame, dataset

Oi,

Estou com a seguinte situação:

tenho um data frame com varias colunas, um grupo delas quero transformar em chave valor. Até ai tudo bem, mas são 2 grupos e eles não podem meio que se repetirem. Tipo, é um grupo de 3 e outro de 3

```
NOME      A1   A2    A3    B1    B2    B3
batata     6   4     7      2    1      1
maçã       9   4     8      1    2      0
```

eu fiz o gather 2 vezes, uma para A1 A2 A3 e outra pra B1 B2 B3. O problema é que o numero de linha resultante é 2*3*3 = 18, pois ele pega um resultado do A e faz uma linha para cada resultado do B

```
NOME    keyA    valueA    keyB    valueB
batata   A1       6        B1       2
batata   A1       6        B2       1
batata   A1       6        B3       1
maçã     A1       9        B1       2
maçã     A1       9        B2       1
maçã     A1       9        B3       1
```

..........(mesmo processo com A2 e A3)

O que eu preciso que é para cada valor de A1, eu tenho apenas a key B1, de A2 apenas B2, etc. Assim:

```
NOME    keyA    valueA    keyB    valueB
batata   A1       6        B1       2
batata   A2       4        B2       1
batata   A3       7        B3       1
maçã     A1       9        B1       1
maçã     A2       4        B2       2
maçã     A3       8        B3       0
```

Apenas 6 linhas

Alguém consegue me ajudar? XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aqui vai uma solução:

```
library(tidyverse)

x <- data.frame(
  NOME = c("batata", "maça"),
  A1 = c(6, 9),
  A2 = c(4, 4),
  A3 = c(7, 8),
  B1 = c(2, 1),
  B2 = c(1, 2),
  B3 = c(1, 0)
)


x %>%
  gather(keyA, valueA, starts_with("A")) %>%
  gather(keyB, valueB, starts_with("B")) %>%
  filter(parse_number(keyA) == parse_number(keyB))
```

A função `parse_number` pega apenas a parte numerica de uma variável, e assim você pode usá-la para comparar as colunas keyA e keyB para pegar somente o que você precisa.

Comment: Daniel, eu tinha feito exatamente isso. Acabe ide abrir aqui para postar a mesma resposta que vc colocou kkkkkk. Mesmo assim muito obrigado!

Comment: kkkk que bom! li seu pensamento :P

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando como base o resultado obtido da tua função gather, fiz um comparativo das colunas para obter o novo `data.frame`. Observe que eu crio um vetor de comparação lógica dos números contidos nas colunas `keyA` e `keyB` e aplico este vetor para selecionar as linhas do `data.frame`.

```
produtos <- data.frame(nome = c('batata','batata','batata', 
                            'maça', 'maça','maça'), 
                   keyA = c('A1','A1','A1','A2','A2','A2'), 
                   valueA = c(6,6,6,9,9,9), 
                   keyB = c('B1','B2','B3','B1','B2','B3'), 
                   valueB = c(2,1,1,2,1,1))

library(stringr)
produtos[str_extract(produtos[,2], '\\d') == str_extract(produtos[,4], '\\d'), ]
```

Comment: ontem pensando, cheguei a uma possível solução com filter. Vou testar ela aqui e depois posto. Se não ter certo ai vou tentar isso ai que me passou. Valeu!